# bash insert word at first position in file using sed

Tags: sed

How can I use `sed` to insert a word at the first line of a file at start position.
For instance I have the file witn the following content:

```
that is a test without scope
that is the second line
that is the third line
```

The result should be:

```
[TICKET_NUMBER] that is a test without scope
that is the second line
that is the third line
```

I'm trying this, but I get the following error:

```
sed -i -E "1s/^[$ISSUE_ID]/ " $COMMIT_EDITMSG_FILE
```

> sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command

I've followed some examples, but I can not make any progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```sh
sed "1s/^/$ISSUE_ID /" file

[TICKET_NUMBER] that is a test without scope
that is the second line
that is the third line
```

Here:

- `1s` will apply `s` command on first line only
- `^` will match line start
- `"..."` will let shell variable expand